# Yocto - generate debug symbol of all the included packages

Tags: build, yocto, bitbake, debug-symbols, openembedded

I am trying to build debug symbols to be used with gdb when needed. To build debug symbols, added below in the target image target-image.inc file.

```
IMAGE_GEN_DEBUGFS = "1"                                                         
IMAGE_FSTYPES_DEBUGFS = "tar.bz2"
```

After a successful build, it generates "target-image-dbg.rootfs.tar.bz2", but this includes very few libs/bins under ".debug".

Below is my yocto distribution

```
DISTRO = "poky"                                                                  
DISTRO_NAME = "Poky (Yocto Project Reference Distro)"                            
DISTRO_VERSION = "2.0.3"                                                         
DISTRO_CODENAME = "jethro"
```

I want to build dbg symbols for all the packages included in my rootfs. Can someone point, what's missing?

Answer (score 1):

You lacked to include `dbg-pkgs`, it is mandatory for this case.

Try to configure this way in your `conf/local.conf`.

```
INHIBIT_PACKAGE_DEBUG_SPLIT = "1"
INHIBIT_PACKAGE_STRIP = "1"
DEBUG_BUILD = "1"
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES_append = " dbg-pkgs"
```

Comment: Why set INHIBIT_PACKAGE_DEBUG_SPLIT/INHIBIT_PACKAGE_STRIP? _"the OpenEmbedded build system strips binaries and puts the debugging symbols into ${PN}-dbg. Consequently, you should not set INHIBIT_PACKAGE_STRIP when you plan to debug in general"_

Comment: This is needed to ensure that in the process of building, debugging symbols aren't stripped by Yocto from the binaries it packages. Adds the symbols and debug info files onto the filesystem as separate files instead of having them embedded with the executables.

Comment: @CleitonBueno - tried with the above suggestions, but the output is the same. I am seeing the target-image-dbg.rootfs.tar.bz2 but the total size of it is 20 MB but my actual rootfs size is  ~150MB. During the build, I see that under "tmp-glibc/work/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/my_package/1.0-r0.release/packages-split/my_package-dbg/.debug/my_package"  during while do_package_qa. I need it to be part of dbg-rootfs.tar.bz2. But its getting deleted. Suggestions?

Comment: @SD., could you attach the full content of your `local.conf` and share the link?

Comment: @CleitonBueno - please see https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/BDxxDDMHqJ/

Comment: @SD. try this https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/tY73b44Xz3/

Comment: Explaining:
Add `dev-pkgs dbg-pkgs tools-debug` and remove customizations regarding DEBUGFS